# LINQ equivalent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails, and i am wondering is there any concept like LINQ in Rails?

I am trying to store values in an object and query the object without saving it in database,
as like in LINQ?

is it really possible in Rails?

Please suggest.

thanks.

Comment: I think you need to supply more details of exactly what you're trying to do... "store values in an object" is really vague.  I'm assuming that you're creating several objects (of the same class? different classes?) into a Hash or an Array.  There are several "LINQ-like" things you can do with these Ruby collections (select, max, min, each, etc.) - they won't use the same syntax as LINQ, but you should be able to do similar activities to what you would do with LINQ in .NET languages.

Comment: I am trying to have a temporary storage, where i can place my data and query it (like order by etc.,) Yes, like storing data in a hash and retrieving value from it by using order by..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find your answer in the [ActiveRecord Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: I have gone through this.. but it seems active record always needs a database table to work with.. but what i am expecting is an object, where i can save data temporarily and query it as per my need...
is it really possible? or anything wrong with my idea?

Comment: If it's an object that doesn't match anything in your models (tables), then I'd think it would just be a Ruby object. Do you have a specific example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: Yes.. i have.. for example i want to store the values pid:22,pname:xxx,pprice:32 and pid:24,pname:xxx1,pprice:34 and pid:23,pname:xxx2,pprice:33 in an object...
and query it like Obj.orderby("pprice DESC")... is it possible?

Comment: I guess I meant why do you have to store it temporarily? Why *wouldn't* you be storing that information in a table of products that you can query with `Product.order("pprice DESC")`?

Comment: in my application i need to sort product listing which are coming from api frequently.. so using database will take more time, this is the reason why i am looking for a temporary save location like object..

Comment: Okay, I see. You could put it into a hash table when you import it. Check any number of hash table questions on this site. Rails isn't ideal for your situation, though. Rails is more suited to sites based on models.

Comment: You could use Redis as a storage mechanism for something like this, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you are looking for something like LINQ to Object approach.
I think you can try to look to [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/) and this [post](http://nutrun.com/weblog/2008/05/29/datamapper-without-a-database.html).